# Limit the overall cache size in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using CachedNetworkImage + ListView.builder + StreamBuilder + Firebase. The layout has a lot of lists as well as grid views, since it is a chat app. The issue is, that after a small amount of time, the overall app size is 2gb+ (tested on iOS). Guess after some usage of my chat app, it will be even higher. Any idea, how I can limit the overall cache size in flutter to, for example, 1.0GB?

Answer (score 0):

Call: 
Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled:true, cacheSizeBytes: 100000000);

Set the cacheSizeBytes to size you want.

Comment: Does it restrict the cache size on the device the app is installed on?